# Example Fourier descriptor algorithm using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

can anyone please give/show me an example for Fourier Descriptor algorithm for 2D basic image (black and white colour rectangle and circle) using matlab but without using toolbox..really need your help..tq

Comment: You will have to be more specific in order to get answers here...

Comment: actually my instructor was asking me to analyse 2D digital image which is rectangle,square and triangle by using Fourier descriptor..that image is firstly drawn by using MS Paint and the color is black and white..he don't want me to use toolbox and he asking me to find a Fourier descriptor algorithm in matlab...so if you have any ideas I am pleased to hear it :)

Comment: So, please share this information with us. Update your question accordingly and add a link to at least one of the images. What exactly do you mean by "Fourier descriptor"?

Comment: Fourier descriptors is a well known term, any search engine will provide answers for that. Now, what is pointless is the enforcement of Matlab in the question.

Comment: sorry for the late feedback...quite busy..huhu...ok let say i want to analyse a black circle with a white background as shown in this link http://i1342.photobucket.com/albums/o766/Ainchan_Shinchan/circle_zps3b3b1c6e.jpg ...can someone give me an idea how to do that using Fourier Descriptors method in matlab (to obtain the value of that circle image)..tq

Comment: i agreed with mmgp...we can find lot about FD via the internet...but unfortunately until now i still can't find about example of FD's Algorithm in matlab...that's why i really need your help guys...so if anyone got the solution or link about FD's algorithm example i'll be glad to see it :)